# how to display proper small icon for notification is not getting displayed in Lollipop and Android M

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-notifications

I am creating an application, I am able to display notification properly, but small icon is not getting displayed as I have mentioned it in the drawable folder, The icon is getting masked with white color. Can any one help me, how can I get the icon to display properly.

Below is my notification code:

```
nb = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
        .setContentText(contentText)
        .setSmallIcon(icon)
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.micon_notification))
        .setWhen(when)
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
        .setTicker(tickerText)
        .setColor(Color.RED);
```

The icon mentioned in drawable is as shown below:

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggYCY.png
```

That complete red color present inside the image is getting vanished and icon is getting displayed with complete white color. All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code Android uses to display notification icons:

```
if (entry.targetSdk >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    entry.icon.setColorFilter(mContext.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
} else {
    entry.icon.setColorFilter(null);
}
```

For that you've to make icon like Silhouette and make some section Transparent wherever you wants to add your Colors.

[image: Iconography]

You can add your color using

```
.setColor(your_color_resource_here)
```

NOTE : setColor is only available in Lollipop so, you've to check OSVersion

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
    ...
} else {
    // Lollipop specific setColor method goes here.
    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
    ...
    notification.setColor(your_color)
    ...            
}
```

Look at the documentation: http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

there are words:

> "Notification icons must be entirely white. Also, the system may scale
>   down and/or darken the icons."

I hope it helps!

Comment: I have used set color, its adding color to the background of icon, Not working with setcolor method.

Comment: In the icon.setColorFilter, what is entry??

Comment: yes setColor is for changing background color. you have to design different icon like shown in above image for lollipop. on pre-lollipop version you can use existing icon. you can also follow iconography link.

Comment: it's just android source code to explain you that android itself set filter to white color for lollipop that's why your existing icon appears white in lollipop

Comment: here is link: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html about android lollipop notifications changes

Comment: Ok Thanks., I will check these out.